# How to engrave?

Tags: modeling, add-on

How do i engrave or put desired seams or thin crevices in objects?. I've included a pic for an example. Is there possibly an addon i could get to make such things easier or more intuitive?. Types of engraving i'm shooting for. straight lines, curved or crescent lines and abstract shapes/designs.[image]

Comment: You will have to create decals for these sigils/symbols. Once you have them DecalMachine or Engraver add-on could be useful for this task. You could also use the Boolean modifier directly.

Comment: So i would need to make these in something like Gimp or Photoshop first?.

Comment: OMG! that DecalMachine addon looks sweet as $%##@ lol.

Comment: @Mingo yes or as actual geometry.